# Does every non-trivial finite group have a subgroup with prime index?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be any non-trivial finite group.

> Has G always a subgroup, whose index is prime ?

If G is solvable and |G| has a prime divisor $p$, such that $p^2$ does not divide $|G|$, this is the case because of Hall's theorem.

If $G$ is a $p$-group, the answer is also positive.

The group $A_5$, for example, is not solvable, but has subgroups with index $5$.

So, I wonder whether we always can find a subgroup with prime index.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647483/prove-that-a-6-has-no-subgroup-of-prime-index/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. The first counterexample I can think of is $A_8$. The largest prime factor of $|A_8|$ is seven. But if there were a subgroup $H$ of index $p\le7$, then there would also be a non-trivial homomorphism $\phi:A_8\to S_p$. More precisely, the natural action of $A_8$ on the collection $X=A_8/H$ of left cosets of $H$ given by
the rule $g\cdot (xH)=(gx)H$ is a homomorphism from $A_8$ to $Sym(X)\simeq S_p$. Because the action is transitive, the homomorphism is not trivial.

But because $|S_p|\le |S_7|<|A_8|$, $\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)\unlhd A_8$ is necessarily a non-trivial normal subgroup contradicting simplicity of $A_8$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why there would be a non-trivial homomorphism?

Comment: @Jyrki what about the solvable groups ? Is there a counter-example as well ?

Comment: @Thomas. Sorry about being overly terse earlier. Hopefully it's better now.

Comment: For the solvable case, please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Indeed, @Andreas. I had a blind spot there. For a moment at least :-)

Comment: ... Why doesn't the same reasoning work for $A_6$?

Comment: I just found this counter-example with GAP. PSL(2,8) and SL(2,9) are the next ones.

Comment: Good question, @DustanLevenstein! It does seem to work for $A_6$ as well. I guess the special properties of $A_6$ steered me higher.

Comment: @Peter So, did GAP prove that $A_6$ has minimal order among groups with this property? Or did it just confirm that $A_6$ is an example? Or were you in fact referring to $A_8$ in your latest comment?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Well, a minimal example is clearly simple, so one would just need to check $PSL(3,2)$ of order $168$ and whether this has a subgroup of index $7$, which it does according to GAP (two conjugacy classes of such in fact).

Comment: I checked all groups with an order having at least three prime factors upto at least the size of the third group I mentioned, so $A_6$ is the smallest counterexample followed by $PSL(2,8)$ and $SL(2,9)$.

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869383901904) is relevant.

In it, Robert Guralnick classifies - using the classification - the finite simple groups that have a subgroup of prime-power index.

---

**Added** The case of solvable groups.

If $G$ is a solvable groups, then $G' < G$, where $G'$ is the derived subgroup. Now $G/G'$ is an abelian group. Find a subgroup $H/G'$ of prime index in it, and pull it back to a subgroup of prime index $H$ in $G$.

Answer (score 2):

> $A_n$ , has no subgroup of prime index iff $n \geq 6$ and $n$ is not prime .

Because of this theorm :
**Theorem :** If $G$ is a simple group with subgroup of index $m>1$, then  $$|G|\quad |\quad m!$$ **Proof :**  if $G$  has subgroup $H$ , and $G$ act on the cosets of $H$, then we have homomorphism from $G$ to $S_m$ with trivial kernel (because $G$ is simple).
Of course $A_{p-1} \triangleleft A_p$ .$\Box$

For another examples , because only normal subgroups of $S_n ( n \geq 5)$ are $ 1 , A_n $and $S_n$, by the same way you can show there is no subgroup of index $2<r<n$ in $S_n$ .

Comment: You would want to require $m>1$, but otherwise OK +1. Your final sentence could be a bit more elaborate; you are trying to explain why $n$ should not be prime. And of course you are using the numeric fact that $\frac12n!>m!$ for any $m<n\geq 6$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks , I fixed $m>1$.