# Prove that $A_6$ has no subgroup with prime index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that it is a fact that $A_6$ has no subgroup of prime index. As can be seen here: [Prove that $A_6$ has no subgroup of prime index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647483/prove-that-a-6-has-no-subgroup-of-prime-index) or here [Does every non-trivial finite group have a subgroup with prime index?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692943/does-every-non-trivial-finite-group-have-a-subgroup-with-prime-index).
However, all the proofs I've seen so far used the fact that $A_6$ is simple or the later link using a non trivial homomorphism additionally. Is there any way to show it differently? I have a gut feeling that one can show it using the Sylow theorems. Sadly I haven't found a way yet to do so.

Furthermore, are there any other groups rather than some form of $A_n$ such that the group has no subgroups of prime index?

Comment: The fact that $A_6$ is simple, is a very basic fact. I am not sure whether it makes sense not to use it. Even if it works, it will be longer and perhaps using similar arguments as in the proof of simplicity. So why not use the standard facts.

Comment: The result is as follows in general: *The alternating group $A_n$ has no subgroup of prime index if and only if $n \geq 6$ and $n$ is not prime.* More generally, see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869383901904).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks a lot for the additional information!

Comment: Brute force is one way.

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove that the group $A_6$ has no subgroups of prime index.

We will not use the fact that $A_6$ is a simple group, and we will also dispense with the notion of a normal subgroup.
However, we will use Sylow's theorem that Sylow subgroups are conjugate.
The proof turns out to be rather long.

Let $H<A_6$ and $|A_6:H|=p$. Clearly, there are three possibilities for $p$ for $p=2,3,5$.

**Case $p=5$.**
In this case $|H|=72$. By virtue of Sylow's theorem, we can assume that the subgroup $P$
consisting of eight elements
$$
P=\{e, (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3), (1,3,2,4)(5,6), (1,4,2,3)(5,6), (3,4)(5,6), (1,2)(5,6)\}
$$
is contained in $H$.
Moreover, since $|H|$ is divisible by $9$, $H$ contains two independent cycles of length $3$: $(1,i,j)$ and $(k,l,m)$.
Next, we have a few cases to consider.

Let $(1,2,5)\in H$. We have $(1,2,5)(1,3)(2,4)=(1,3,2,4,5)\in H$ and $|H|$ is divisible by $5$.
Contradiction.

The cases when a cycle of length $3$ of $H$ includes exactly two symbols from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ are treated similarly.

Let $(1,5,6)\in H$. So $(1,5,6)(1,3,2,4)(5,6)=(1,3,2,4,5)$. Contradiction.
The case  $(i,5,6)\in H$ is treated in a similar way.

We have considered all cases (why?).

**Case $p=3$.**
In this case $|H|=120$.
We still assume that $P<H$.
Let $(1,2,3,4,5)\in H$.

> Lemma 1. $A_5=\langle(1,2,3),(3,4,5)\rangle$.

I leave the proof to the author of the question.

We have
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,2)(3,4)=(1,3,5)\in H$ and
$(1,2)(3,4)(1,2,3,4,5)=(2,4,5)\in H$.
From lemma 1 it follows
$\langle(1,3,5),(2,4,5)\rangle=A_5<H$.

Next, since
$$(1,3,2,4)(5,6)(1,2,3,4,5)(1,4,2,3)(5,6)=(1,6,3,4,2)\in H$$
and
$$(1,6,3,4,2)^{-1}=(1,2,4,3,6)\in H$$
we have
$(1,2,4,3,6)(1,2)(3,4)=(1,4,6)\in H$ and
$(1,2)(3,4)(1,2,4,3,6)=(2,3,6)\in H$.
As above, it follows from lemma 1 that
$\langle(1,4,6),(2,3,6)\rangle=A_5(1,2,3,4,6)<H$.

Then $(1,2,5),(3,4,6)\in H$ and $|H|$ is divisible by $9$.
Contradiction.

The cases when a cycle of length $5$ of $H$ contains all four symbols $1,2,3,4$ in any order and one of the symbols $5$ or $6$ are quite similar to the case we have considered.

Let $(1,2,3,5,6)\in H$.
Since
$(1,2,3,5,6)(1,3)(2,4)=(1,5,6)$ and
$(1,3)(2,4)(1,2,3,5,6)=(1,4,2)$ and so on as in the case above.

**Case $p=2$.**
In this case $|H|=180$.
We may consider that
$$\langle(1,2,3),(4,5,6)\rangle<H.$$
Furthermore $H$ contains some cycle of length $5$.  Here I will be very brief. I recommend to prove by yourself the following lemma from which it is easy to get a contradiction in this case.

> Lemma 2.  If $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary cycles of length 3 and 5
> respectively, then $\langle a,b \rangle=A_5$.